# Only require some folders from Composer and install to custom path

Tags: php, composer-php

I am starting to work on a new, longer running php project. I want to separate my files from the frameworks files as good as possible, to be able to update the framework without having to separate my files from the framework's files.

In Java, I'd use maven and have everything put in a lib folder. From there, I'd import the libs into my code. I learned that the same tool for php is composer (or I suspect so ;)) but I struggle to start using it.

I configured the project and composer in phpstorm and added a composer.json file, which looks like this (I removed the personal information):

```
    {
  "name": "example",
  "description": "description_text",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "author's name",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.*",
    "laravel/laravel": "v5.2.*",
    "components/jquery": "2.2.*",
    "components/font-awesome": "4.6.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "laravel/laravel/public"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to move everything into laravel's public folder, where Bootstrap and jQuery belong AFAIK (the path is basing on the observation, that laravel itself is placed in vendor/laravel/laravel). But of course, then laravel also gets put there.

On top of that, composer downloads more than I need. For example, I only need the content of bootstraps dist folder (css and js for bootstrap 4(and from them, only the min files)) but it also installs docs etc.

Because I'm not experienced in this, I don't know if what I want is possible or how to do it. I suspect that many of my problems come from the fact that I try to install laravel and the other stuff all in the same composer.json file.

Could you help me? :)

Regards

Christian

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `composer.json` for **php** stuff and `jspm` for JS related code? Why are you mixing it all with php package manager? With `jspm` this is trivial, look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure) Laravel doc you want to place all "frameworks" in `vendor` dir which yes includes Laravel so remove your config composer.json.

> The `vendor` directory contains your Composer dependencies.

Where you are trying to place items is for your resources

> The `public` directory contains the front controller and your assets (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.).

`app` is where you would place your classes and such.

As for these frameworks being bloated a bit with unneeded files I have not found a great way to clean them up outside of manually removing them all.

I was trying to draw a conclusion between maven and composer but it was making the post way bigger then I'd like. You are correct that this is the closest thins to a PHP maven.

**EDIT**

A better answer to your question as I re-read it is that your code is as tied to a framework version as it needs to be. I doubt any version during development will break backwards compatibility. At least I hope not and if you know of a new version coming maybe get on a beta/dev/nightly release.

As for my above statement is that composer is designed to work with this structure in the way described. When you want to use the psr-4 autoloading portion of composer as well this will help you greatly.

In any case think of vendor as your .m2 local repo.

Comment: Hi nerdlyist and thank you for your reply! Okay, if I understand you right, you are proposing to download laravel "in the normal way" and THEN modify the composer.json of the downloaded copy to require bootstrap and jQuery? 

I don't know if this would be a "cleaner" way to go, but a possibility I imagine is using git submodules. With this, I could also keep laravel up to date during development, but I wouldn't get rid of the excess files as well.

Comment: @Christian no from what I can see in the Laravel doc there is a `bootstrap` directory that should handle the bootstrap need for you. Anything else you deem needed as frameworks will be added with composer install to `vendor`.